# When adding a Local Business Schema, is it wrong to have the same @type of business in different Markups of the same page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, velo

I was recently adding some Markups to a Wix website and got a weird recommendation. The site told me that I shouldn't add the same @type (the type field of my JSON-LD format) in two Markups that are located in the same page—[picture of this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQEp1.png)

I would like to use the same @type because inside of that page you have all our business locations and they all do the same type of business—[page I'm refering to](https://www.covidtests.com.mx/los-cabos). After getting this recommendation I looked all over the place for some explanation as to why this is wrong and found nothing; I'm just woried that this may affect my site's performace.

PS: I tried to add a markup for each location's page, but Wix does not allow schemas on dynamic pages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Google's guidelines for Multiple departments](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/local-business#multiple-departments)** to mark up your departments. You can also use the **[array element to create a list](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#representing-lists-as-arrays)** for your offices in JSON-LD format:

```js
"@list": [
      {"@value": "joe"},
      {"@value": "bob"},
      {"@value": "jaybee"}
    ]
```